# Angular Slow View Performance

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

I am experiencing a slow view issue and would like a help or tip on how to get around this. My problem is view processing, not requests.

The situation is as follows:

I started to realize that during browsing the pages get slow, and starts to even lock the page scroll. I did the following test: I have a Dashboard page and another with a list of items. Logically, entering the site I am directed to the Dashboard, and at this moment, when opening the List page, it is slow. If I press F5 while in the list page it becomes normal, and the scroll goes smooth, but if I go to another route and back there it starts to crash, sometimes even on the other pages there are several crashes in the view.

I'm using Lazy loading, and don't have any .subscribe getting open, I either applied the Async pipe or I force Unsubscribe in the ngOnDestroy method.

I tried to identify the problem by Inspect, but the memory consumption is constant during browsing, in short, I found nothing to clarify what is happening.

Anyone out there been through this? Do you know where the problem is and how to get around?

Comment: Hard to help you without code, versions, etc.

Comment: Usually when you face problems like this, the first troubleshooting step is isolate the problem to a single component. Do it and post the code of that component

Comment: Exactly, the problem is probably in my code, unfortunately I can't make it available here. I just asked if anyone has had this kind of problem and have tips on how to get to the solution. 
about testing a component separately doesn't work because the problem happens when I navigate between the routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into the `OnPush` change detection strategy to optimize change detection. This can dramatically improve application performance.

Read [this article](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/) and [this article](https://itnext.io/onpush-change-detection-for-faster-angular-apps-f5d6dccea589) to get an idea on how adjusting the change detection strategy can help.

Essentially, the default change detection strategy for all components is to run change detection *every time* that *anything* changes in the app.

If you switch your components to use `OnPush`, the framework won't have to run change detection on those components unless their inputs change or one of their events are triggered. There are also ways of manually running change detection on a component (`detectChanges()` and `markForCheck()`. The `OnPush` strategy seems sensible, especially for "dumb" or "child" components that receive their state from their parent.

The best method of refactoring your methods to use the `OnPush` strategy is starting with the "leaf" components (not the parent components) and working your way up. These child components are less likely to depend on the default change detection strategy.

Here's an example of setting the `changeDetection` property in your `@Component()` decorator.

```js
@Component({
  template: `
    {{count}}
    <button (click)="increment()">Increment</button>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CounterComponent {
  count = 0;

  increment() {
    this.count++;
  }

}
```

The `ChangeDetectionStrategy` enum can be imported from `@angular/core`.

Comment: Great! 
I followed your tip, and yet I still had some occurrences of the problem. but your tip helped solve it.
But the biggest problem I had in my code is an AOS (Animate Scroll Libary). I don't know why the library generated this slowness, because I've always used it in my web systems, but the moment I removed it from my code, all pages stopped crashing during changes to the view. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Glad you figured out the culprit.

Comment: Oh wow, you saved me hours and hours of debugging. I also had the AOS library installed. I removed it and app is now super fast!